# How do I update my Nodejs in laravel dev. to LTS

Tags: php, laravel

How do I update my Node to LTS? I keep getting errors when I try  "npm install" in my terminal. Please help

> npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
>   npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.2.14: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
>   npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail on node releases >= v7.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to
>    find it in the tree.
>   npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
>   npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\Goodness\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "--no-bin-links"
>   npm ERR! node v4.4.6
>   npm ERR! npm  v3.10.9
>   npm ERR! code ENOGIT
>
> npm ERR! not found: git
>   npm ERR!
>   npm ERR! Failed using git.
>   npm ERR! This is most likely not a problem with npm itself.
>   npm ERR! Please check if you have git installed and in your PATH.
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>   npm ERR!     C:\xampp\htdocs\event\npm-debug.log

Comment: Where is this? Server, your own computer, virtual machine? Seems like a simple download will fix this: https://nodejs.org/en/

Comment: My local server

Comment: As I said, just download and install a newer version of node from the website

Comment: I have done that. still I find it difficult to use vue.js with my laravel project